# Error: No suitable method found for add(String)

Tags: java, arrays, string, swing, methods

I am getting this only one error message every-time I'm running the program. This is a small part of my code:

```
JFrame f; JPanel p1;
int i=0, m=0;
int[] subbb = {0,1,2,3};
String[] status = {"Add", "Repeat"};
String[] comboStat = {"combo_status1", "combo_status2","combo_status3", "combo_status4"};               
JComboBox combo_status1, combo_status2, combo_status3, combo_status4;
JComboBox combo_set_panel = new new JComboBox(subbb);

combo_status1=new JComboBox(status); combo_status2=new JComboBox(status);
combo_status3=new JComboBox(status); combo_status4=new JComboBox(status);

for(i=0; i<4; i++) {
   if (combo_set_panel.getSelectedIndex() == subbb[i]) {
      for(m=0; m<=subbb[i]; m++)
      {
         p1.add(comboStat[m]); //Error Message Shows This Line
      }
   }
}

f.add(p1);
```

But, while running this program. I am getting this error Message:

```
Add a String: error: no suitable method found for add(String)
```

Anyone please tell me a solution for this error. 
What is the suitable method for `add(String)`?

Answer (score 1):

What is `ComboStat`? (That soon will be called `comboStat` because you'll follow the [Java Naming Conventions](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm) :)) It's an array of Strings.

Of what type is `p1`? It's a `JPanel`.

`add` accepts a `Component` and `String` **is not** a `Component`.

You probably wanted to do:

```
p1.add(new JLabel(ComboStat[m]));
```

In order to insert the [`JLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html) (Which **is** a `Component`):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

problem is here in this line

```
combo_status1=new JComboBox(status);
```

You are passing array instead of String